# What's special about flights SU 6496, 1883 and 1895?

Tags: air-travel, covid-19, russia

According to [IATA's rules](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php) on entering Russia:

> Passengers are not allowed to enter.
>
> - This does not apply to:
> - nationals of the Russian Fed. and their family members;
>   ...
> - nationals and residents of Belarus if arriving from Belarus (**not traveling on flights FV/SU6496**);
> - nationals and residents of Kyrgyzstan if arriving from Kyrgyzstan (**not traveling on flights SU1883 and SU1895**).

What's special about these three flights? Why does Russia specifically exclude them?

Comment: I believe SU1883 and 1895 are not normal scheduled flights (well that's obvious from the question). By the wording on https://www.aeroflot.ru/ru-en/covid-19?_preferredLanguage=en&_preferredLocale=ru (see section on Kyrgyzstan), it seems that these flights are reserved only for certain categories of foreigners (diplomats, highly qualified workers, family members of Russian citizens etc.) (or that foreigners are allowed on these flights only). But the reasoning why it was put on IATA is not obvious to me at the moment.

Comment: But when I try to book a flight from Bichkek to Moscow, SU1883 does appear as a normal flight with no special indication...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My wild guess is that these are reserved to be purely repatriation flights for now.

So, you can theoretically enter as a Kyrgizian citizen from Bishkek to Moscow, but the only flight that would allow you to do that is still reserved for repatriation only, so you still can't.

The SU6496 case is very strange since it's a domestic Kazan-SPb flight. Maybe they were meaning the `SU 1843` Minsk-Moscow?

Comment: You can buy tickets on both SU1883 and SU1895 from Bishkek and Osh to Moscow for every weekday morning...

Comment: I don't see why not; I'm just not sure you will be able to *board* it unless you're on Russian passport.